# I broke python: what can I do?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a big problem on my Ubuntu 64 bits...

I tried to clean a python test I made when I had compiled a modified python version. But I think I broke everything :s

now, when I launch cmd "python3", I have:

```
>python3
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Aborted
```

I can't "apt-get install python3.3" and I can't remove it...

I tried:

```
apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

nothing

I don't no what I can do now...

**EDIT:**
I think too much is broken. Luckily, I backed up my VM a week ago. So I restored it as before.

Next time that I would like to reinstall a package properly, I will use "sudo apt-get install - reinstall python3". (thanks)

However I think we can't uninstall python3 when it is compiled at home (https://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-to-install-python-3-3)....
"make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop." :)

thank you all !

Comment: try `apt-get purge python3.3 && apt-get update && apt-get install python3.3`

Comment: Apologise to it nicely? :P

Comment: I already tried ^^
make Apologize
make: *** No rule to make target `Apologize'.  Stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reinstall python:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
```

Comment: did not know about the  --reinstall option. Thanks!

Comment: There are a problem during reinstallation: Reading package lists [...] Setting up python3.3-minimal (3.3.0-1) ... python3.3: can't open file '/usr/lib/python3.3/py_compile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory. But your answer is most useful for future readers so I accepted. ;-) (my problem is solved. see edit)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try an `apt-get remove python-3.3`, then `apt-get clean`, `apt-get update`, and then `apt-get install python-3.3` ?

Comment: When I try "apt-get remove python-3.3", it want remove many of important program: "The following packages will be REMOVED: ..." :s (my problem is solved. see edit)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need it to work and don't care about the old setup you could download python and compile it in some specific location and just run it from there.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-to-install-python-3-3

Comment: I've already done this but I can't compile it with -fPIC to used it with a C++ lib and the author told me to use official package to avoid problems... (my problem is solved. see edit)